# Passing an async option value with Angular

Tags: angular

This is the view:

```
<select name="day" (change)="showHourRange(value)">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose one</option>
  <option *ngFor="let delivery of deliveries$ | async"
          [value]="delivery.day">{{delivery.day | date:'dd/MM/yy'}}
  </option>
</select>
```

The value logs undefined when the method is called even if it is correctly shown inside the rendered options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ngModel] and ngModelChange

```
<select name="day" [ngModel]="selectedDelovery" (ngModelChange)="showHourRange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let delivery of deliveries$ | async"
          [value]="delivery.day">{{delivery.day | date:'dd/MM/yy'}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Although this solves the problem, it also rises another one. The placeholder static option now has disappeared. I've updated the view code, this line was removed for legibility.

Comment: @cerealex you mean the disabled `choose one` option is no longer in the DOM?

Comment: Strangely enough, it is in the dom, but not shown as selected option in the view... (The box is empty)